# Programmer Dvorak keyboard layout not persisting at startup

Tags: debian, keyboard-layout, lxde, dvorak

I am using Debian with LXDE.  I want to use the [programmer Dvorak](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/) keyboard layout.

I am currently using a GUI that I added to the panel called “Keyboard Layout Handler”.

These are the current settings:

[image]

I have also bound the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to <kbd>Control</kbd>.

I would appreciate help with these two things.

1. The keyboard layout does not persist when I restart my computer.  It switches back to qwerty on restart.  It is qwerty when I am prompted to decrypt LVM and when signing in as a user.
2. I would like to know how to do this using the command line instead of using a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install keyboard-configuration.

```
apt-get install keyboard-configuration
```

Then you will be able to select the keyboard you want off of a list.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  Looking at https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard helped me get it working for when I am prompted to decrypt LVM as well as once I am signed in.  But the login page is still qwerty.  Any suggestion on how to get the keyboard layout working on the login page.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard#Keyboard_configuration was helpful to get it working after I had signed in.  https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard#How_to_set_keyboard_layout_in_initramfs was helpful to get it working when prompted to decrypt LVM.